# Oracle SQL find popular query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got a table called Questionnaire in SQL where there are columns named ID, Newspaper and CreditCards. I need to output the newspaper that is most popular among IDs who has at least 3 creditcards.

Example:

```
ID       Credit Cards    Newspaper
----------------------------------------
10354    3               The Independent 
12154    4               The Independent 
11354    2               The Times 
14587    3               The Daily Mail 
19874    5               The Sunday news 
16847    1               The Independent
```

Can you please help with an sql command to output the query stated above?

Comment: If your DB supports Rank(), then it can be used as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from (
    select newspaper, 
           rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
    from Questionnaire
    where credit_cards >= 3
    group by newspaper
) t
where rnk = 1
```

If two newspapers have the same "popularity" both will be returned.

SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/16dcb/1

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get only the most popular Newspaper[s], then this can solve the query.

```
select 
    newspaper
    , count(1) as fct 
from 
  Questionnaire 
where 
  CreditCards >= 3
group by newspaper 
having fct = 
            (
              select 
                max(ct) 
              from 
                ( 
                    select 
                        newspaper 
                        ,count(1) as ct 
                    from 
                        Questionnaire 
                    where 
                        CreditCards >= 3 
                    group by newspaper
                )
             )
/
```